# Showing that $\mathsf{Cov}(f(X), g(Y)) \geq 0$ for non-decreasing $f$ and $g$ taking values on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> We have two non-decreasing functions $f$ and $g$ and a random variable $X$. We want to show that $\mathsf {Cov}(f(X),g(X))\geqslant 0$.

Intuitively, it makes sense, but how do I formalize this?

Comment: What are "non-decreasing $X$ and $Y$"?

Comment: @d.k.o. I have tried to simplify the problem from what it originally was. We have two non-decreasing functions $f$ and $g$ and a random variable $X$. We want to show that Cov$(f(X), g(X)) \geq 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74677/covariance-of-increasing-functions

Comment: Also look up "FKG inequality".